# I want set up an app bar but failed, how to solve that problem?

Tags: android, kotlin

https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up

I just follow this instruction, but the toolbar doesn't show on my screen, and there's an error

[image: mainctivity]

[image: this is my xml file]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please, visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do not post images of code, include it in the question.

Comment: Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) instead of post them as image

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know Kotlin, but I think your problem lies in that you are using the SupportActionBar so the activity should extend AppCompatActivity, not Activity. Try having your activity extend AppCompatActivity and let me know if it helps!

Comment: after extending AppCompatActivity, it works, but there still an error on" my_toolbar"

Answer (score 0):

yes, in activity set setActionBar and check manifest xml file which theme used.

Comment: I have changed the theme to NoActionBar, still not works